# How do I convert String to Instant concatenating a date string to a time string?

Tags: java, datetime, time, simpledateformat

I need to convert this String to a Instant, i do it this way:

```
String inputStartDate = startDate+" 00:00:00.000";
String inputEndDate = endDate+" 23:59:59.999";
```

startDate is only the date because i get the String from another call, but i need to keep the hour static, the same way to the endDate.

Then, i convert to Instant like this:

```
Instant newStarDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(inputStartDate).toInstant();
Instant newEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(inputEndDate).toInstant();
```

But when i convert to instant, it's convert wrong.
For example:

```
startDate="2022-02-04"
endDate="2022-02-04"
```

When i do the concat the string is like this:

```
inputStartDate: "2022-02-03 00:00:00.000"
inputEndDate: "2022-02-04 23:59:59.999"
```

And the result when i transform to instant it's like this, i don't know what is wrong.

```
newStartDate:"2022-02-03T03:00:00Z"
newEndDate:"2022-02-05T02:59:59.999Z"
```

I need the yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS to do a mongodb query and it's need to be a Instant.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat only returns a simple date.

Comment: You have a learning curve ahead of you.  Dealing with dates, times _and timezones_ is a complex subject that is not easy to master.  You need to be familiar with the classes in `java.time.*`

Comment: Don’t use `23:59:59.999` to represent the end of the day. You are leaving out 999 999 nanoseconds of the day. Use the first moment of the following day and consider it exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, it was more easier than i think.

Instead of giving it a SimpleDateFormat you have to transform it directly to Instant like this:

```
Instant finalStartDate = Instant.parse(startDate+"T00:00:00.000Z");
Instant finalEndDate = Instant.parse(endDate+"T23:59:59.999Z");
```

You have to add the T and the Z.